# jQuery collection gets broken inside each loop (remove elem, restore innerHTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, foreach

I expected the following code to iterate through a select options and remove options having a certain value, otherwise restore the select html

```
var initialHTML = $('#myselect').html();

$('#myselect option').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'b'){
        $(this).remove();
        console.log('matching. removed.');
        return false;
    }else{
        $('#myselect').html(initialHTML);
        console.log('not matching. html restored.');
    }
});
```

Expected select would be:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

but it actually is

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

What I'm doing wrong? [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/eLynjy8L/)

**Update** e.g. as someone suggested:

> The `$('#myselect option')` constructs a list of options, and
>   `$(this).remove()` removes option `b`, but the list of options is no
>   longer linked to the HTML, because the HTML had been already changed
>   by `$('#myselect').html(initialHTML)` which was executed for option
>   `a`

so, I've realised that the actual problem is not even related to what I asked initially in my question. Sorry for that and I'll try to put it in the right section.

p.s. **a working solution**:

```
var initialHTML = $('#myselect').html();

function doIt(){
    $('#myselect').html(initialHTML);

    $('#myselect option').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() === 'b'){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you so much for help.

Comment: When you restore the HTML inside the `<select>` (when the option value is "a"), the selector for `$('#myselect option')` will not reference the new `<option>` elements. What is the purpose of restoring the original HTML?

Comment: Just so we avoid an XY problem here, what is your actual goal here, that this logic is supposed to be doing?

Comment: @j08691 If it continued to `c`, wouldn't we see another "not matching. html restored"? I think the issue is that the loop is iterating a specific selector, and then those elements are replaced, so the selector no longer references anything.

Comment: @Eliellel an option without a set `value=""` will default the value to the options html.  You can see this in action by adding a `console.log(this.value)` to their fiddle.

Comment: @Taplar I've tried also with value having same result.

Comment: @neoDev ignore the logic that you have for a moment.  Please tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Taplar I am trying to properly understand it and the reason why it is not stopping.

Comment: @showdev Yes, I believe you're correct

Comment: Then you are asking us to solve the problem with your code, when what you should be asking us about is how to solve your original problem, which this code is meant to do.  That's what we are missing right now while we try to avoid the XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Are you just trying to remove any option that has a value of `b` and leave the others?

Comment: This might help to explain: "The set of elements contained within a jQuery object will not change unless explicitly modified. This means that the collection is not "live" – it does not automatically update as the document changes. If the document may have changed since the creation of the jQuery object, the collection should be updated by creating a new one." -- [jQuery Object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/#jquery-objects-are-not-quot-live-quot). Also, here is an [example to help demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/uav0ojy6/1/).

Comment: guys thank you helping me understand the actual problem. Now I realise also it is not even relative to what I asked originally in my question. Sorry for that maybe I'll create a new question for that instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is this line:

```
$('#myselect').html(initialHTML);
```

It is executed for option `a` and then option `b` can no longer be removed because the HTML has changed even though it is actually identical. So remove that line and your code will work.

`$('#myselect option')` constructs a list of options, and `$(this).remove()` removes option `b` from the list, but the list is no longer associated with the HTML, because the HTML had been already changed by `$('#myselect').html(initialHTML)` which was executed for option `a`.

```js
var initialHTML = $('#myselect').html();

$('#myselect option').each(function() {
  if (this.value === 'b') {
    $(this).remove();
    console.log('matching. removed.');
    return false;
  } else {
    //$('#myselect').html(initialHTML);
    console.log('not matching. html restored.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
  <option>c</option>
</select>
```

I changed `$(this).val()` to `this.value`. Both will work, but the second one is a bit more efficient because there is no point in converting the JavaScript object to a jQuery object just to get the value.

However, remember that the line:

```
return false;
```

will cause the `each()` loop to exit once a match is found. That's OK if there will only be one match. If there can be more that one match, remove that line so the loop can go through all options.

Comment: What you suggest is same as just: `$select.each(function(){ if (this.value === 'b') $(this).remove() })`... this is not what I am trying to understand... please read comments

Comment: What does that mean *this is not what I am trying to understand*? I already explained to you why it is doing that. The `$('#myselect option')` constructs a list of options, and `$(this).remove()` removes option `b`, but the list of options is no longer linked to the HTML, because the HTML had been already changed by `$('#myselect').html(initialHTML)` which was executed for option `a`.

Comment: Ok it makes sense now. Thank you for helping me understand the actual problem

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative way:

Other answers already point out the reason, as because you refresh the option list the during the first iteration, `$(this).remove()` no longer works because it lose contact of the original item. Thus, a simple fix here would be re-select the target based on it's value. And you can keep your original code of `$('#myselect').html(initialHTML);` in the loop.

```js
var initialHTML = $('#myselect').html();
$('#myselect option').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() === 'b'){
        $("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").remove();
        console.log('matching. removed.');
        return false;
    } else { 
        $('#myselect').html(initialHTML);
        console.log('not matching. html restored.');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect">
    <option value='a'>a</option>
    <option value='b'>b</option>
    <option value='c'>c</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes it works, because that dynamic selection does not care if the jQuery collection is eventually broken.. it makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
you don't need else part as it is already present and put your jquery inside document.ready so that it will ensure DOM is ready and you can run the jquery script.

```
var initialHTML = $('#myselect').html();
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#myselect option').each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == 'b'){
            $(this).remove();
            console.log('matching. removed.');
            return false;
        }
    });
   });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t99w1gb/8/)

Comment: In your example initialHTML is not used at all... I need it instead e.g. for eventually restore the select again once some of those options were removed. Please help me understand the actual problem instead.

Comment: @neoDev, Do you have any trigger point on which you decide what to remove and when to restore html. you can use that event and call script

Answer (score -2):

What is happening here is that you have something that only needs to be false once to restore the entire select. So it does remove 'b' when it finds it, but then restores the whole select once it sees that 'c' !== 'b'.

You can achive your expected behavior by removing:

```
else{
    $('#myselect').html(initialHTML);
    console.log('not matching. html restored.');
}
```

Depending on what your ultimate goal is, there may be better ways of approaching this, though.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But `false` is returned when the value is "b", stopping the loop. It never gets to "c".

Comment: Very true. I overlooked that.